# Datasets for Document Classification problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, text-classification

I am doing a project to make a application that can take pdf and docx documents as input and classify them into various categories such as
- Financial
- Government and Political
- Sports and Entertainment
- Technology and Scientific
- Sensitive ( Personal and Government )
But I was not able to find enough data that can be used to train the ML model.

Can you please point me to some places where I could find data sets that could be used for my project. I currently only have the BBC news dataset. I would prefer if the datasets are in .txt format or in a format that can be converted to .txt with some code or software.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Providing datasets is outside of the SO scope.

Comment: As a thought experiment, though -- where do you go for technology news? Where do you go for sports scores? Did you know that Google and other search engines could look up specific document types, such as PDF?

Comment: If you're specifically looking for the programming involved to convert a PDF to raw text, then SO is a great place to ask. You have to pose the right question, though.

Comment: You should ask this question on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)